# How to correctly architect message sending in 1-to-1 chat?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, architecture, chat, backend

I see it like every unimportant action is sent by client directly to socket channel ('start_typing', 'finish_typing' for example). But sending message should be POST REST method, which performs custom validation, logic, persisting; after all things are done, it sends message to socket channel.

Is it correct way to do this? Or I should rather just send message to socket channel from client?

Comment: do you mean private chat?

Comment: @Kashif Direct message, for example.

Comment: can you put some code so I can understand properly?